# Getting a visa for Malaysia in Bangkok (Swedish passport)

Tags: visas, passports, malaysia

Getting a visa for Malaysia in Bangkok.

Hello,

I have a Swedish passport.

Normally I would not need a visa to visit Malaysia for up to three months.

But I would like to get a visa anyway before going there.

Is it possible for me to get a visa at the Malaysian embassy in Bangkok?

Also, how much would it cost?

Vesa

Comment: Why get a visa when you dont need one?